# How do components re-render in redux using hooks

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to conceptualize redux and its working, and after some testing, I have noticed a thing. I would like to quote this example

lets say, I have a single reducer (a boolean variable). based on that variable, the following code happens.

reducer

```js
const initState = { isLoggedIn: false };
const isLoggedInReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOG_IN":
      return { ...state,isLoggedIn: true };
    case "LOG_OUT":
      return { ...state,isLoggedIn: false };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default isLoggedInReducer;
```

action

```js
export const logIn = () => {
    return {
        type:'LOG_IN'
    }
}

export const logOut = () => {
    return {
        type:'LOG_OUT'
    }
}
```

index.js

```js
<Provider store={createStore(isLoggedInReducer)}>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact>
            <AppScreen />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/auth">
            <AuthScreen />
          </Route>
          <Route path="*">
            <NotFoundScreen />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
```

so, my app firstly directs the user to a component called "mainScreen" , which is as follows

```js
const AppScreen = () => {
  let isLoggedIn = useSelector((state) => state.isLoggedIn);
  if (isLoggedIn)
    return (
      <>
          <button onClick={() => dispatch(logOut())}>unauthenticate</button>
          <NavBar />
          <Content />
          <BottomBar />
      </>
    );
  else{
    return (
      <>
        <Redirect to="/auth" push />
      </>
    );
  }
};
```

so if the reducer state has value TRUE , my navbar and stuff is shown, else the user is redirected to the "authScreen" , which is as

```js
const AuthScreen = () => {
  let isLoggedIn = useSelector((state) => state.isLoggedIn);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return isLoggedIn ? (
    <>
        <Redirect to="/" push />
    </>
  ) : (
    <>
      <h1> auth is {isLoggedIn?"true":"false"}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(logIn())}>authenticate</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

This creates a setup where "authScreen" can toggle the reducer to TRUE and it re-renders, and finds that reducer is TRUE, so it renders the "mainScreen". Vice versa for "MainScreen"

Now, what components actually re-render ? If I place my authenticate button in the "navbar" instead as a sibling to "navbar" , will it re-render the "navbar" or the "mainScreen" ?

How does redux calculate what component to re-render when a peice of state changes ? How does the useSelector fit in, when I did not even use "connect".

Using hooks with redux made it very confusing. I am sorry if my explanation is hard to understand. The code actually works, I just don't know how.
Any piece of information is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Using Redux with a UI always follows the same basic steps](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-5-ui-react#integrating-redux-with-a-ui):

- Render components using initial state
- Call `store.subscribe()` to be notified when actions are dispatched
- Call `store.getState()` to read the latest data
- Diff old and new values needed by this component to see if anything actually changed.  If not, the component doesn't need to do anything
- Update UI with the latest data

React-Redux does that work for you internally.

So, `useSelector` decides whether a component should re-render based on whatever data *you* return in your selector functions:

https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-5-ui-react#reading-state-from-the-store-with-useselector

If the selector return value changes after an action was dispatched, `useSelector` forces that component to re-render.  From there, [normal React rendering behavior kicks in, and all child components are re-rendered by default](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/05/blogged-answers-a-mostly-complete-guide-to-react-rendering-behavior/#standard-render-behavior).

Please read my post [The History and Implementation of React-Redux](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/11/react-redux-history-implementation/) and talk [A Deep Dive into React-Redux](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2019/06/presentation-react-redux-deep-dive/) for details on how React-Redux actually implements this behavior.

Comment: If I move the useSelector call inside of a child component of some component X, will it still force the parent X to re-render ? Because that is whats happening with my code (More specifically from the above example, the button lying in the appScreen component when moved to Navbar, which is a child of appScreen, it still causes appSceen to re-render instead of Navbar)

Comment: No. Like all hooks, `useSelector` only directly affects the component it's inside of.  But, as I said, React always re-renders recursively by default, so any components _inside_ of there will re-render too.